# want to make stored procedure with table name and table data as input parameter

Tags: mysql

create sp_insert 
@tablename varchar(20),
@tabledata udtAdminType

set @var =''
@var ='Insert into '+@tablename+'values(column name 1,column name 2,column name 3)values'+@tabledata

exec(@var)

my table is dynamic so  i am not able to insert data and it is not allowing me to store table in variable

Comment: Did you have a question? Your "question" is tagged with mysql, but what you have shown looks more like SQL Server syntax than it does MySQL syntax. (In MySQL, procedure argument and variable names don't start with `@` character, string concatenation is with the CONCAT function, not a the `+` operator, `exec` isn't valid MySQL function, et al.

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insert( @tablename varchar(20), @tabledata TEXT)
BEGIN  

    SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',@tablename ,' (column name 1,column name 2,column name 3) VALUES (',@tabledata,')');   
 PREPARE stmt from @s;   
 EXECUTE stmt;   

END;
```